# Collect all key errors

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

I want to create a class which will store a list of key errors occured in **init**.

```
class Basic:
    missing_view_data_columns = []

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        self.some_dict = some_dict
        try:
            self.basic_1 = self.some_dict['basic_1']
            self.basic_2 = self.some_dict['basic_2']

        except KeyError as e:
            self.add_missing_data_column(e)

    @classmethod
    def add_missing_data_column(cls, column_name):
        cls.missing_view_data_columns.append(column_name)


class Specific(Basic):

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        super().__init__(some_dict)
        try:
            self.specific_1 = self.some_dict['specific_1']
            self.specific_2 = self.some_dict['specific_2']

        except KeyError as e:
            self.add_missing_data_column(e)


rem = Specific({})

print(f"missing_keys: {rem.missing_view_data_columns}")
```

This is my approach, but it doesn't work. Following code will print only first key error that appeared.
Also I can tell that it doesn't look too good because I need to write same exception twice.

Could you give me advice how to create this functionality?

Comment: If `specific_1` is not in the dictionary, do you still want to check if `specific_2` is?

Comment: Dict will be handed over to class by downloading data from web page, and I need to know if this dict contains every key defined in init.

Comment: why are both key lookups inside the `try`? the second one is guaranteed to be ignored if the first one raises a `KeyError`, as the `try` block will be exited on the first line

Comment: I just wanted to show what I want achieve. In my code I plan to have more than 2 keys and I don't want to create 10 times try except block.

Comment: @Beorn perhaps you could wrap the `try` `except` in a for loop for each key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own dictionary:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

class MissingDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, d, cls):
      self._d = d
      self.cls = cls

    def __getitem__(self, i):
      if i in self._d:
          return self._d[i]

      self.cls.add_missing_data_column(i)

    def __iter__(self): return iter(self._d)
    def __len__(self):  return len(self._d.keys())
```

This will store the dictionary instance and update your class's missing list whenever you try to access a new key. Use like this:

```py
class Basic:
    missing_view_data_columns = []

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        self.some_dict = MissingDict(some_dict, self)
        self.basic_1 = self.some_dict['basic_1']
        self.basic_2 = self.some_dict['basic_2']

    @classmethod
    def add_missing_data_column(cls, column_name):
        cls.missing_view_data_columns.append(column_name)


class Specific(Basic):

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        super().__init__(some_dict)
        self.specific_1 = self.some_dict['specific_1']
        self.specific_2 = self.some_dict['specific_2']


rem = Specific({})

print(f"missing_keys: {rem.missing_view_data_columns}")
```

Displays:

```
missing_keys: ['basic_1', 'basic_2', 'specific_1', 'specific_2']
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code to loop over each key you want to check:

```
class Basic:
    missing_view_data_columns = []

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        self.some_dict = some_dict
        keys = ['basic_1', 'basic_2']
        for key in keys:
            self.check_for_key_error(key)

    def check_for_key_error(self, key):
        try:
            self.key = self.some_dict[key]
        except KeyError as e:
            self.add_missing_data_column(e)

    @classmethod
    def add_missing_data_column(cls, column_name):
        cls.missing_view_data_columns.append(column_name)


class Specific(Basic):

    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        super().__init__(some_dict)
        keys = ['basic_1', 'basic_2']
        for key in keys:
            self.check_for_key_error(key)


rem = Specific({})

print(f"missing_keys: {rem.missing_view_data_columns}")
```

Output:

`missing_keys: [KeyError('basic_1'), KeyError('basic_2'), KeyError('basic_1'), KeyError('basic_2')]`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you actually want to store the exception messages? Because it looks like you just want to know which keys are missing from the dictionary. If that's the case, you should just look in dictionary.keys().

```
keys_to_look_for = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_n"]
return [k for k in keys_to_look_for if k not in some_dict.keys()]
```

You could also use the `dictionary.get()` method, which returns `None` if the key isn't present. You can set a default return value if it fails, like `dictionary.get(something, "return this if not found")`. This would, however, exclude keys that are in the dictionary but whose value is `None`.

```
return [k for k in keys_to_look_for if not some_dict.get(k)]
```

Comment: what if the `key` is present and its value is `None`? You should just use `if key in`